# Issue with Prepared Statement when using "?"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Well, my question concisely is "When I wrote the ? in place of the table name it gave no action "
like here, suppose I have..

```
String full = "update ? set name = ? where id = ?";
```

but when I remove the first ? and type the table name "Everything goes perfect" ... Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JDBC, the `?` placeholder stands for a value, and it cannot stand for an identifier such as a table name.  It can be used where a literal value can be used.  You'll notice you can't have the `?` where a column name is expected either.

Comment: This isn't just for JDBC - this is for all parameterized queries.  You can't parameterize a tablename or column name

Comment: Funny thing is, with MySQL Connector/J the replacement of placeholders with parameter values happens in the driver, not serverside. With this driver - contrary to drivers that actually prepare the query serverside - you can use a `?` everywhere, it just gets replaced with a quoted string; so for MySQL it only doesn't work 'by accident' because the resulting query is `update 'theTableName' set ....` which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use placeholders for table names.